# Why is ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate method slow?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrentdictionary

I am working on a thread safe multi valued dictionary. Internally this dictionary uses a Concurrent dictionary (.net 4.0) with a custom linklist as value. Same key items are added in the linklist. The problem is when I use concurrent dictionary's AddOrUpdate method *(approach 1)* to insert an item, the code runs a bit slow as compared to when I use a TryGetValue method to check whether the key is present or not and then add or update the value manually inside a lock *(approach 2)*. It takes around 20 seconds to insert 3 million records using the first approach, whereas using the second approach it takes around 9.5 seconds on a same machine (Intel i3 2nd generation 2.2 ghz & 4 Gb ram). There must be something missing which I am not able to figure out yet.

I have also checked the code for concurrent dictionary but it seems to do the same thing as I am doing inside a lock:

```
public TValue AddOrUpdate(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> addValueFactory, Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> updateValueFactory)
    {
        if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key"); 
        if (addValueFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("addValueFactory");
        if (updateValueFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("updateValueFactory"); 

        TValue newValue, resultingValue;
        while (true) 
        {
            TValue oldValue;
            if (TryGetValue(key, out oldValue))
            //key exists, try to update 
            {
                newValue = updateValueFactory(key, oldValue); 
                if (TryUpdate(key, newValue, oldValue)) 
                {
                    return newValue; 
                }
            }
            else //try add
            { 
                newValue = addValueFactory(key);
                if (TryAddInternal(key, newValue, false, true, out resultingValue)) 
                { 
                    return resultingValue;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for thread safe multi valued dictionary (approach 2 is commented, uncomment it to check the difference).

Update: There are Remove, Add and other methods also which I have not pasted below.

```
class ValueWrapper<U, V>
{
    private U _key;
    private V _value;

    public ValueWrapper(U key, V value)
    {
        this._key = key;
        this._value = value;
    }

    public U Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
    }

    public V Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}

class LinkNode<Type>
{
    public LinkNode(Type data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
    public LinkNode<Type> Next;
    public Type Data;
}

public class SimpleLinkedList<T> 
{
    #region Instance Member Variables
    private LinkNode<T> _startNode = null;
    private LinkNode<T> _endNode = null;
    private int _count = 0;

    #endregion

    public void AddAtLast(T item)
    {
        if (_endNode == null)
            _endNode = _startNode = new LinkNode<T>(item);
        else
        {
            LinkNode<T> node = new LinkNode<T>(item);
            _endNode.Next = node;
            _endNode = node;
        }

        _count++;
    }

    public T First
    {
        get { return _startNode == null ? default(T) : _startNode.Data; }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
    }

}

class MultiValThreadSafeDictionary<U, T>
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<U, SimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>>> _internalDictionary;

    private ReaderWriterLockSlim _slimLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();


    public MultiValThreadSafeDictionary()
    {
        _internalDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<U, SimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>>>(2, 100);
    }

    public T this[U key]
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            /* ****Approach 1 using AddOrUpdate**** */


            _internalDictionary.AddOrUpdate(key, (x) =>
            {
                SimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>> list = new SimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>>();
                ValueWrapper<U, T> vw = new ValueWrapper<U, T>(key, value);
                list.AddAtLast(vw);
                //_internalDictionary[key] = list;

                return list;
            },

            (k, existingList) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    _slimLock.EnterWriteLock();

                    if (existingList.Count == 0)
                    {
                        ValueWrapper<U, T> vw = new ValueWrapper<U, T>(key, value);
                        existingList.AddAtLast(vw);
                    }
                    else
                        existingList.First.Value = value;

                    return existingList;
                }
                finally
                {
                    _slimLock.ExitWriteLock();
                }
            });


            /* ****Approach 2 not using AddOrUpdate**** */

            /*
            try
            {
                _slimLock.EnterWriteLock();

                SimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>> list;
                if (!_internalDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list))
                {
                    list = new SimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>>();
                    ValueWrapper<U, T> vw = new ValueWrapper<U, T>(key, value);

                    list.AddAtLast(vw);

                    _internalDictionary[key] = list;
                    //_iterator.AddAtLast(vw);
                    return;
                }

                if (list.Count == 0)
                {
                    ValueWrapper<U, T> vw = new ValueWrapper<U, T>(key, value);
                    list.AddAtLast(vw);
                    //_iterator.AddAtLast(vw);
                }
                else
                    list.First.Value = value;
            }
            finally
            {
                _slimLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
            */

        }
    }
}
```

The test code only insert items, all with unique keys. It is as follows.

```
MultiValThreadSafeDictionary<string, int> testData = new MultiValThreadSafeDictionary<string, int>();

    Task t1 = new Task(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                testData[i.ToString()] = i;
            }
        }
    );

    Task t2 = new Task(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 1000000; i < 2000000; i++)
        {
            testData[i.ToString()] = i;
        }
    }
    );

    Task t3 = new Task(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 2000000; i < 3000000; i++)
        {
            testData[i.ToString()] = i;
        }
    }
    );

    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
    t3.Start();

    t1.Wait();
    t2.Wait();
    t3.Wait();

    watch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("time taken:" + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

### **Update 1:**

Based on the answer from '280Z28', I am rephrasing the question. Why is GetOrAdd and 'my' method taking almost the same time, where as in my method I am taking an extra lock and also calling TryAndGet method also. And why AddOrUpdate taking the double amount of time as compared to AddOrGet. Code for all of the approaches is as under:

GetOrAdd and AddOrUpdate method in ConcurrentDictionary (.net 4) has the following code:

```
public TValue GetOrAdd(TKey key, TValue value)
{
    if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
    TValue resultingValue;
    TryAddInternal(key, value, false, true, out resultingValue); 
    return resultingValue; 
}

public TValue AddOrUpdate(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> addValueFactory, Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> updateValueFactory)
{
    if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key"); 
    if (addValueFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("addValueFactory");
    if (updateValueFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("updateValueFactory"); 

    TValue newValue, resultingValue;
    while (true) 
    {
        TValue oldValue;
        if (TryGetValue(key, out oldValue))
        //key exists, try to update 
        {
            newValue = updateValueFactory(key, oldValue); 
            if (TryUpdate(key, newValue, oldValue)) 
            {
                return newValue; 
            }
        }
        else //try add
        { 
            newValue = addValueFactory(key);
            if (TryAddInternal(key, newValue, false, true, out resultingValue)) 
            { 
                return resultingValue;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

GetOrAdd in my code is used as follows (taking 9 seconds):

```
SimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>> existingList = new SimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>>();
existingList = _internalDictionary.GetOrAdd(key, existingList);
try
{
    _slimLock.EnterWriteLock();

    if (existingList.Count == 0)
    {
        ValueWrapper<U, T> vw = new ValueWrapper<U, T>(key, value);
        existingList.AddAtLast(vw);
    }
    else
        existingList.First.Value = value;
}
finally
{
    _slimLock.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

AddOrUpdate is used as follows (taking 20 seconds on all adds, no updates). As described in one of the answers this approach is not suitable for update.

```
_internalDictionary.AddOrUpdate(key, (x) =>
{
    SimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>> list = new SimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>>();
    ValueWrapper<U, T> vw = new ValueWrapper<U, T>(key, value);
    list.AddAtLast(vw);
    return list;
},

(k, existingList ) =>
{
    try
    {
        _slimLock.EnterWriteLock();

        if (existingList.Count == 0)
        {
            ValueWrapper<U, T> vw = new ValueWrapper<U, T>(key, value);
            existingList.AddAtLast(vw);
        }
        else
            existingList.First.Value = value;

        return existingList;
    }
    finally
    {
        _slimLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
});
```

Code without AddOrGet and AddOrUpdate is as follows (taking 9.5 seconds):

```
try
{
    _slimLock.EnterWriteLock();

    VerySimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>> list;
    if (!_internalDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list))
    {
        list = new VerySimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>>();
        ValueWrapper<U, T> vw = new ValueWrapper<U, T>(key, value);

        list.AddAtLast(vw);

        _internalDictionary[key] = list;
        return;
    }

    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        ValueWrapper<U, T> vw = new ValueWrapper<U, T>(key, value);
        list.AddAtLast(vw);
    }
    else
        list.First.Value = value;
}
finally
{
    _slimLock.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

Comment: Just as a side thing, how can you have an i3 core 2 duo.. you can have an Intel Core i3 2nd Generation or 3rd Generation. Or you can have an Intel Core 2 Duo

Comment: Yep its a mixup. Its Intel i3 2nd generation. Thanks for pointing this.

Comment: It is quite curious that the "always lock exclusively" approach is faster considering that your workload is 100% non-conflicting writes. This is the worst case for approach 2 and the best case for approach 1. In approach 1 only the "add" delegate is being called, right? The update delegate is never being called.

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary was optimized for the common case, the case where contention is rare and improving concurrency by holding a lock for a very short time is desirable.  You are however testing the uncommon case, extreme contention.  You couldn't make it worse, other than by adding more tasks.  Seeing that taking a lock only once for the basic operation being faster than locking multiple times when there's contention is therefore no surprise.  Profiling this reliably is not simple, you'd have to test real production code.

Comment: @HansPassant his writes are 100% on non-conflicting keys. The only contention he should be seeing is spurious lock striping contention.

Comment: @usr writes are unique, yes, but as I have seen the concurrent dictionary code, it inserts items in array of linklist and locks are taken on the linklists. More than one 'unique' items can still fall in same linklist and can create contention.

Comment: It *can* but the lock striping is designed to result in *spurious* conflicts. They are meant to be rare and I do not see evidence that they aren't.

Comment: @usr - you cannot know, the hashing function matters.  And the hashing buckets can be reorganized completely when the dictionary grows.

Comment: I'd expect the string hashing function to be tested for integer keys after 10 years of .NET... The hashing function is the last place to look at. So far, everything I have seen in this question and answers was highly speculative. Time to use a profiler (or pause the debugger a few times).

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `AddOrUpdate` for this code. This is extremely clear because your update method never actually updates the value stored in `ConcurrentDictionary` - it always returns the `existingList` argument unchanged. Instead, you should be doing something like the following.

```
SimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>> list = _internalDictionary.GetOrAdd(key, CreateEmptyList);
// operate on list here

...

private static SimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>> CreateEmptyList()
{
    return new SimpleLinkedList<ValueWrapper<U, T>>();
}
```

Comment: Good point. I have replaced it with GetOrAdd and running time has improved to 9.5 seconds (against 20 sec for AddorUpdate). But what I am not getting is that the 'other' code (using TryGetValue to add or update inside a lock) is also taking the same time i.e. 9.5 sec yet it does 'more' work. Besides, my test code only inserts unique keys, 'update' was not working in AddOrUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

> Read operations on the dictionary are performed in a lock-free manner.
>   As mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx

Implementation of AddOrUpdate is using fine-grained lock so to check if item already exists or not, but when you first read by yourself, being lock free read it is faster and by doing that you are reducing locks required for existing items.

Comment: But before reading an item, using TryGetValue method, I am taking a write lock. Wouldn't this result in the same overhead?

Comment: Your Lock has nothing to do with Concurrent Dictionary's Lock. Of course your lock is slow, but Add0rUpdate method has its own internal lock. And you dont need lock of any kind when you use Concurrent Dictionary, locking is automatically managed.

Comment: I will definitly need a lock, b/c it is 'multi valued' dictionary implementation. If more than one key-value pairs with same key are added then they are accomadated in a list (SimpleLinkList). If more than one thread are adding items with 'same key' at the same time, then without lock implementation would not be threadsafe. Plus, the lock I am taking is an extra lock (besides concurrent dictionary's internal lock), the code should be slow, rather it is faster than AddOrUpdate.

Comment: Instead of using one lock for all lists inside dictionary, you can use list itself as lock, so you are not blocking operations of other list, concurrent dictionary will do its job.